# Let $\pi$ be the quotient map $S^n\to\mathbb R\mathrm{P}^n$. Is $\pi_{\star p}:T_pS^n\to T_{\pi(p)}\mathbb R\mathrm P^n$ an isomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, quotient-spaces, projective-space, spheres, tangent-spaces

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> *Let $\pi$ be the quotient map $S^n\to\mathbb R\mathrm{P}^n$. Then $\pi_{\star p}: T_pS^n\to T_{\pi(p)}\mathbb R\mathrm P^n$ an isomorphism*

Here is my attempt:

---

*Proof.* Since $\dim S^n=\dim \mathbb R\mathrm P^n= n$ we only have to check that $\pi_{\star p}$ is surjective. Indeed, let $Y_{\pi(p)}$ be a vector in $T_{\pi(p)}\mathbb R\mathrm P^n$ and $\alpha:(-\xi,\xi)\to\mathbb R\mathrm P^n$ be a smooth curve such that $\alpha(0)=\pi(p)$ and $\alpha'(0)=Y_{\pi(p)}$. Then there exists another curve $\beta:(-\delta,\delta)\to S^n$ such that $\pi\circ\beta=\alpha$. This implies that:
$$\pi_\star \beta'(0)=(\pi\circ\beta)'(0)=\alpha'(0)=Y_{\pi(p)}$$
Thus $\pi_{\star p}$ must be surjective.

---

**How can I ensure the existence of that curve $\mathbf{\beta}$?**

Comment: This is a standard lemma proved when studying covering spaces. The curve you want is called a lifting of $\alpha$. Under some very mild assumptions such a $\beta$ always exists.

Comment: For each $p\in S^n$, consider an open hemisphere $H_p$ which contains that point (for example, in $S^2$, if you consider the point $p=(0,0,1)$, then consider the hemisphere $\{(x,y,z)\in S^2\,:\, z>0\}$). Now, $\pi$ maps $H_p$ bijectively onto its image (because $\pi$ sends $x$ and $-x$ to the same point in the quotient, but by restricting to a single hemisphere, we avoid this issue), and by looking at the charts, you can convince yourself that the inverse of this restriction is smooth. In short, $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism, simply by looking at the explicit formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true because $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism. See [Why does the projection $\pi:(a,b,c) \in S^2 \to[a,b,c] \in P^2$ have rank 2 everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4340698) for $n =2$. You can easily generalize this to arbitrary $n$.